# What can a US citizen do regarding the theft of Mt Gox PII data (Passports, etc)

Tags: mtgox, privacy

[A hacker is selling](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2014-03-11/isnt-it-ironic-mtgox-hacker-demands-ransom-exchange-users-not-reveal-their-personal-) Personally Identifiable information (PII) stolen from Mt Gox.

What can a US citizen do to protect their identity?  What steps should they take?

- [Should a passport be cancelled?](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/lost-stolen.html)
- Should I do anything with my credit report, or state license?

Comment: You might get better answers at money.se.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identity theft protection.

Comment: This is not related to the question per se, but do you have some proof that this data is currently being sold?

Comment: Yes there is plenty of evidence... Pastebin and Bitcoin talk have it. If this isn't closed tomorrow when i get to a computer I'll update will all the relevant links.  He's now doing extortion... Asking for .5 btc to not sell your data.

Comment: @SalvadorDali added link.. there are more.

Comment: Wow, this is really sad. Directors of mtgox should be jailed for such blatant irresponsibility about customers data...

Comment: There no specific evidence that the data is being sold, but the people who have it claim they are selling it.